# Is 郵便 exclusive to Japan Post in this reading problem?

Tags: readings, jlpt

The question is a the bottom since the context may be an issue.
Here is a problem from a study text (kanzen master N1 reading)

以下は（株）ANTONIOのホームページに掲載されていたおしらせである。問いに対する答えとして最もよいものを一つ選びなさい。

「マリア・ホセ・ペレス　フラメンコショー」公演延期のお知らせ

３/１９（月）南町ホールにて予定しておりました「マリア・ホセ・ペレス　フラメンコショー」は、本人急病のため、急きょ公演延期とさせていただくことになりました。ファンの皆様には、多大なるご迷惑をおかけいたしますこと、深くお詫び申し上げます。

つきましては、以下の日程で延期公演を行います。

延期公演日程

５・２２（火）南町ホール　開場・１８：００　開演・１８：３０
３・１９（月）のチケットをお持ちの方は、延期公演にそのままご入場いただけます。チケットを大切に保管いただき、延期公演当日に持ちください。

尚、チケット代金の払い戻しを希望されるお客様は、以下のどちらかの方法でお手続きをお願い致します。いずれの場合も払い戻し期限は４・１９までとさせていただきます（郵送の場合は４・１９必着）

１。プレイガイドまたは弊社での手続き

チケットを買い求めのプレイガイドあるいは弊社にて、払い戻し手続きをお願い致します。３・１９のチケットと引き替えにお手続きをいたします。

２。郵便によるお手続き

払い戻し先情報（お名前、ご住所、お電話番号、金融機関名、支店名、口座番号、口座名義）を記入したメモをチケットとともに封書にて弊社まで送りください。その際葉ならず簡易書留でおお願いします。送りいただいた際の郵便代金は、払い戻し金振込時に、併せてご指定の口座に振り込みます。お振り込みはチケット到着から3週間後になります。

ご不明な点は以下までお問い合わせください。

２０１２年3月１４日

。。。

問い：サムさんは南町駅前のプレイガイドでチケットを買ったが、5月22日の公演に行くことができない。お金を買えしてもらうのに最も適切な行動はどれか。

１。チケットを(株）ANTONIOへ持って行き、払い戻し手続きをする。

２。チケットを買ったプレイガイドへ、払い戻し先情報を書いたメモとチケットを簡易書留で送る。郵便代金はサムさんが負担するが、後で戻って来る。

３。宅配便で払い戻し先情報を書いたメモとチケットを（株）ANTONIOへ送る。送料は立て替えるが、後で戻って来る。

4。簡易書留で、払い戻し先情報を書いたメモとチケットを(株）ANTONIOへ送る。郵便代金はサムさんが負担する。

The answer guide says the correct answer is the first answer.  It says the third answer is wrong because チケット送付は郵便で行う. I understand the first answer is correct but still have some questions about the answer.

My first question is why is 宅配便 not considered a subset of 郵便 as indicated by チケット送付は郵便で行う- is that term only for the Japanese post office, as opposed to the English 'post' or 'mail' which I assume you can use with other companies?

Also, the sentence ３・１９のチケットと引き替えにお手続きをいたします led me to think going to ANTONIO or プレイガイド and exchanging the tickets would be a ticket exchange and not a cash back refund. Please clarify why this deduction is wrong.

Comment: I think 宅急便 refers to private courier services specialising in parcel delivery.

Comment: I know that this is none of my business, but it makes me a little nervous to see the copy of this amount from a presumably copyrighted material.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I'll take it down if it bothers people. I understand the quantity is larger than a vocab problem, but I still thought it was fair use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use if you want to use U.S. standards

Comment: I do not know if it is fair use under the US copyright law.  After all, it is your post and I am just a bystander.  Please just use your own best judgment.  If you are fine, I have nothing to complain.

Comment: In Japan 郵便 only refers to 日本郵便 (Japan Post) and they only have the service called 簡易書留.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, the directions for mail expressly request 書留 through 郵便. Regardless of whether or not it's allowed by mail, they do ask for that 簡易書留 which is not there in answer 3. I would be more confused about #2 then #3. Generally, though, I would interpret 郵便 to be post and 宅急便 to be Sagawa or something.

For your second question, it says right in the first option 払い戻し手続きをお願い致します. By going there you can get a refund for your ticket.

And just for fun let's break down each of the answers:

1. This is valid as explained in the first option, as you know.
2. Incorrect because you need to send the letter to ANTONIO
3. Incorrect because it's not 書留 through 郵便
4. Incorrect because the answer says he will not be reimbursed for mailing

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: "refund for your ticket or exchange it". What do you mean by exchange it? Exchange it for what?

Comment: My mistake, slight brainfart on the second part.

Comment: 宅急便 is a trademark owned by ヤマト運輸 (Yamato), which is the largest parcel service company in Japan. This is because the question uses the word 宅配便, which is not a brand name.

Comment: Didn't know that about the term 宅急便. The fact that it's kuroneko adds an extra layer of "aha!" to the title 魔女の宅急便, too!

Answer (score 1):

@ssb explains answers the first question well.

As for your second question, ３・１９のチケットと引き替えにお手続きをいたします just means "we will do the procedure in exchange for the tickets". The context that this is the procedure of refunding you comes from the previous sentence.

But in effect, this is just a reminder to bring the tickets when you go for the refund. It's just a "sophisticated" way of saying "bring the tickets, and we'll pay you back"